# Cuda: error C2065:"threadIdx':undeclared identifier

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I am trying to create a Cuda project in VisualStudio 2010. I have created one simple test .cu file which takes an array and adds 1 to all its element and sends the result back to the host.

I have added cudart.lib file to the Linker.

In the .cu code I have included `#include cuda_runtime.h` header.

But when I am trying to compile it, it's giving the two errors.

> error C2065 :'threadIdx': undeclared identifier
>   error C2059: syntax error:'<'

After installing Nvidia Nsight Visual Studio edition and setting the item type of .cu file as CUDA C/C++,it starts giving two additional errors:

> error D8003:missing source filename
>
> error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin" -I"C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\inc" -I"C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\shared\inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include"  -G  --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile  -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MDd  " -o "Debug\test.cu.obj" "\ucigrad.local\Users\AGill\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\cudatest\cudatest\test.cu"" exited with code 2.

Please help me how to resolve it. I think there may be some issue with nvcc compiler in VS2010 but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Also I am using CUDA 4.2.I have selected the Cuda 4.2 in the Build Customization option by right clicking on the project.

Comment: Are you linking the appropriate libraries?

Comment: Yeah I included the cudart.lib.Also when I set the Item Type of .cu file to CUDA C/C++,it gives two additional errors:D8003:missing source filename and error MSB3721.

Comment: You said, `#include cuda_runtime.h` but your real code has quotes around `cuda_runtime.h`, right? :)

Comment: Searching online for "error D8003:missing source filename" indicates that one thing that triggers it is mismatched quotes, for instance around preprocessor definitions. Can you give us the command line for cl? `Property Pages | C/C++ | Command Line`.

Comment: @RogerDahl: Yeah,you are right.Actually somehow it was not able to locate test.cu file and the \Debug folder.So what I did is rather than creating my project at "\ucigrad.local\Users\AGill\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects" folder ,I create it at "D://Projects" folder and its working fine now.Even the other two errors vanished.I don't know the reason but its working fine for me now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you get most likely indicate that you're not compiling your CUDA sources with NVCC. Make sure that you are, either by selecting the appropriate item type (CUDA C/C++) if you have installed the Visual Studio integration when installing the toolkit. Or make sure you have set up appropriate build rules for your sources.

Comment: I have already installed Nvidia Nsight and set the Item type of .cu file as CUDA C/C++.But by doing this it starts giving two additional errors,error:D8003:missing source filename and error:MSB3721 (with a big description along with giving the above two errors.

Comment: Okay, that's the next step. But the problem you asked about is then resolved. What exactly are the errors you get now (their full description)? Perhaps add that to your question. Or maybe make it a separate question if it confuses this one too much. They seem to be separate problems after all.

Comment: I have edited the question with two additional errors.Also prvious errors are not resolved yet.Another thing,I tried one of the example source code(ScalarProd) provided by cuda which is running fine but when I tried to create project from scratch ,these issues occured.

Comment: So you still have the same first two errors complaining about threadIdx?

Comment: Also I have include 3 directories to the Linker.
 1)C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\lib
 2)C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\shared\lib
 3)C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\lib

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking you might have a wrong setting somewhere. A `"` somewhere that shouldn't be there. Something that borks the generated command line. But from glancing at the 4th error message I don't see it. I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Thanks @Bart ,I am able to fix this issue.There is some problem with the path of my Project.I just create a new project at the D:/ drive and its working fine right now.

Comment: Looking at it again I would assume that the dot in \ucigrad.local\ is tripping it up... anyway, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are annoyed by the IDE errors (which still lets your code work without errors) just like I was, try to do plain text search in the SDK`s include folder for the (seemingly) undefined symbols and you will find the right header to include in no time.
"threadIdx" for example resides in "device_launch_parameters.h" header file.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are 2 types of errors - Build errors and IDE errors. Check if build succeeded (you can ignore IDE errors)
2. Try #include "cuda.h" (or with angle brackets)
3. Re-building sometimes solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the problem even following above steps, the solution that worked for me was to change the 'ItemType' to "CUDA C/C++" under  Properties of the .cu file.